# Export compiled CSS and JS from Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress

So you have:

SiteA : Wordpress site

SiteB : Full-scale application (Rails, either way)

My goal is to embed content from SiteA into SiteB. By content I mean post content along with all compiled CSS and JS.

For post content I found a great plugin for Wordpress, WP-API, which returns all of the JSON data associated with each post. Good start. Now for the rest... I'm wondering if either:

1) There's already a plugin written that can accomplish this, or

2) I'll have to write something. I'm not an expert with Wordpress yet, but I guess there would be a way of hi-jacking the bootloader and outputting an all.css and all.js, then write a script to send over those files from SiteA to SiteB every time they're updated. Better yet create an endpoint that just returns all of the CSS and JS and check the diff between that and what's on SiteB every so often.

I want to avoid using iframes to import the content because of the SEO disadvantages, but at least there are workarounds when loading it in with AJAX.

EDIT:::::::

I think I found (part of) what I was looking for...

**/wp-admin/theme-editor.php : lines 79 - 94**
This is where updates to the theme's styles are written to the style.css within the theme directory. I basically duplicated this to write to a separate file, just on my server for now - although easily it can hook into a CDN and write it there - and have SiteB refer to that file. Making progress!

Comment: so scraping? is it all on the same server or? posts are easy, just parse them in with PHP. It would help if you could specify exactly what TYPE of content.

Comment: I did - post content, CSS and JS. Like I said I have post content covered already. And it could be on the same server, to be decided.

Comment: Hi @Meowts, I'm trying to do the very same thing. I have a WordPress website which I want to use as a CMS for a Rails app. I'm using the `kiosk gem` and the `JSON API` plugin. But obviously... depending the theme, the Rails app miss a lot of css and js (WordPress, Theme, Plugins, ...). Can you give me an advice here? I'm not sure how to do it even with the solutions below. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would **recommend**.

‣ Establish a global folder within shared hosting or create one in the cloud CDN.

**1.)** Put both web properties on the **same** server / hosting. *You mentioned you have this option.*

Go into Wordpress and change all the file path references for the `.css` and `.js` files; and any other files you want to be '[global](https://www.google.com/search?q=web%20development%20global%20element&oq=web%20development%20global%20element&aqs=chrome..69i57.5433j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=what%20is%20a%20global%20element)' - and not just specific to the WP install.

*Eg. Something like this:* `/wp/css/styles.css` **-->** `../../css/styles.css`

*(Change reference to reach public shared-global folder)*

Remove these css & js folders / files from the Wordpress CMS install directory to the base directory of your hosting where both web properties can easily share.

```
www.coolwebsite.com/wp/

www.coolwebsite.com/
```

## Or

**2.)** Put all the 'shared / global folders and files' in the cloud on a CDN like [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/). Remove from hosting. This might be easier to manage, you can have the same absolute path for any and all web properties you want to share these common files with.

*EG. similar to how google CDN hosts all these jQuery versions, libraries, and plugins.*

Comment: Cool thanks, I think this might be the right solution!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't setting up a Content Delivery Network (CDN) be more secure?
So both your site can load them.  And will reduce the loading time for both your sites.
You can also use dns prefetch using:

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="url_to_external_cdn_domain" />
```

Comment: Yes that would be a good option for when it's called by SiteB. SiteA will not really be public facing, it's only used to manage the content and styles/functionality within the content. The trick is having what's hosted on the CDN be updated when changes to the CSS or JS (tweaks or when plugins are added) are made on the Wordpress site. 

I'm taking a peek into the loading process by Wordpress, hopefully I'll find somewhere I can maybe plug this in...